# Why Bhagwan Shiva is not seen on Kailash?

Tags: shiva, kailasa

What is the reason why Shiva is not seen on Kailash ? Does he live in invisible form ? Although Shiva is devta, so he obviously doesn't have human like body.

Are all devtas invisible to humans ?

Why ?

Comment: Maybe He is to some....